# Javascript how change text in paragrap after click each button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the text in span after click on button. I have four buttons and I want to change the text after click on each button.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="product" value="2" onclick="setTime(product[this].time)">first button</button>
<button id="product" value="3" onclick="setTime(product[this].time)">second button</button>

            <span id="time">16-20 min</span>
            <span id="water">750 ml</span>
            <span id="salt">10,5g</span>
            <span id="comments">ajsdhaskj</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vegetables.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        setTime(product[0].time);
        setWater(product[0].water);
        setSalt(produkt[0].salt);
        setComment(produkt[0].comment);     



    $('#product').onclick('change', function() {
        var numb = $(this).value();

        setTime(product[numb].time);
        setWater(product[numb].woda);
        setSalt(product[numb].salt);
        setComment(product[numb].comment);

    });

    function setTime(time) {
        $('#time').html(time);
    }

    function setWater(water) {
        $('#water').html(water);
    }

    function setSalt(salt) {
        $('#salt').html(salt);
    }

    function setComment(comment) {
        $('#comment').html(comment);
    }
</script>
```

And my vegeatbles.js

```
var product = [
{name: 'Carrot',time: '12 min',water: '12 min',salt: '12 min',comment: 'Carrot comment'},
{name: 'Potato', time: '123 min', water: '1 ml', salt: '10.5g',comment: 'potato comment'
}]
```

Comment: I think a some more info would be helpful. What is the effect/error? Seems like you are using jQuery. Is it included properly? Btw there is a typo on lines 3 and 4 of your script (you mean `product` not `produkt`).

Comment: Your button ID's must be unique.

Comment: Actually there are many errors in your code

Answer (score 1):

There's a looong list of what's wrong with your code. I probably missed something:

- You can't have several elements with the same id. Use `class` instead.
- Your buttons have values 2 and 3 which you then try to reference to data elements, but there are only two elements, so no 2 or 3 in there.
- You use "#comment" selector to set comments, but the actual id of the element is "#comments".
- Your data is in `product` variable, but you sometime refer to it by `produkt`.
- The `onclick` events on your buttons seem to be redundant since you already attach `setTime` events via jQuery.
- You need to attach events on elements when the page is loaded.

Here's a working remake of your code:

```js
var product = [
{name: 'Carrot',time: '12 min',water: '12 min',salt: '12 min',comment: 'Carrot comment'},
{name: 'Potato', time: '123 min', water: '1 ml', salt: '10.5g',comment: 'potato comment'
}];

jQuery( function( $ ) {
  setTime( product[ 0 ].time );
  setWater( product[ 0 ].water );
  setSalt( product[ 0 ].salt );
  setComment( product[ 0 ].comment );

  $( '.product' ).click( 'change', function() {
    var numb = Number( $( this ).val() );
    setTime( product[ numb ].time );
    setWater( product[ numb ].woda );
    setSalt( product[ numb ].salt );
    setComment( product[ numb ].comment );
  } );
} );

function setTime( time ) {
  $( '#time' ).html( time );
}

function setWater( water ) {
  $( '#water' ).html( water );
}

function setSalt( salt ) {
  $( '#salt' ).html( salt );
}

function setComment( comment ) {
  $( '#comments' ).html( comment );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="product" value="0">first button</button>
<button class="product" value="1">second button</button>
<span id="time">16-20 min</span>
<span id="water">750 ml</span>
<span id="salt">10,5g</span>
<span id="comments">ajsdhaskj</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Look my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/eL92nyvj/)

```
    <body>
<button id="product" value="0" onclick="loadContent(this.value)">first button</button>
<button id="product" value="1" onclick="loadContent(this.value)">second button</button>

            <span id="time">16-20 min</span>
            <span id="water">750 ml</span>
            <span id="salt">10,5g</span>
            <span id="comments">ajsdhaskj</span>
<script type="text/javascript">




var product = [
    {name: 'Carrot',time: '12 min',water: '12 min',salt: '12 min',comment: 'Carrot comment'},
    {name: 'Potato', time: '123 min', water: '1 ml', salt: '10.5g',comment: 'potato comment'
    }]


    function setTime(time) {
        $('#time').html(time);
    }

    function setWater(water) {
        $('#water').html(water);
    }

    function setSalt(salt) {
        $('#salt').html(salt);
    }

    function setComment(comment) {
        $('#comments').html(comment);
    }

    function loadContent(buton){
        setTime(product[buton].time);
        setWater(product[buton].water);
        setSalt(product[buton].salt);
        setComment(product[buton].comment); 
    }

   loadContent(0);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o759x4o7/) of this.

Note: I have changed some variables as well.

```js
    var product = [{name: 'Carrot',time: '12 min',water: '12 min',salt: '12 min',comment: 'Carrot comment'},{name: 'Potato', time: '123 min', water: '1 ml', salt: '10.5g',comment: 'potato comment'}];
 
    $('button').click(function() {
        var num = $(this).val();
        document.querySelector('#time').innerHTML = num;
        setTime(product[num].time);
        setWater(product[num].water);
        setSalt(product[num].salt);
        setComment(product[num].comment);
    });

    function setTime(time) {
        $('#time').html(time);
    }

    function setWater(water) {
        $('#water').html(water);
    }

    function setSalt(salt) {
        $('#salt').html(salt);
    }

    function setComment(comment) {
        $('#comment').html(comment);
    }
```

```html
<button id="product0" value="0">
    first button
</button>
<button id="product1" value="1">
    second button
</button>

<span id="time">16-20 min</span>
<span id="water">750 ml</span>
<span id="salt">10,5g</span>
<span id="comments">ajsdhaskj</span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I mean "product" in every places. I am trying display different cooking times,water, etc for different products. Can I accomplish this with a single function that checks which button was clicked and after that reads appropriate value from my vegetables.js ?

Actually code has no effect after click on button. Before this I tried on select element and it's seemed to work fine. I need to change action of select and using many buttons.

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="product">
    <option value="0">Carrot</option>
    <option value="1">Potato</option>
    <option value="2">Corn</option>
</select>

<span id="time">16-20 min</span>
<span id="water">750 ml</span>
<span id="salt">10,5g</span>
<span id="comments">comment</span>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vegetables.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    setTime(product[0].time);
    setWater(product[0].water);
    setSalt(product[0].salt);
    setComment(produkt[0].comment);     

 $('#product').onchange('change', function() {
    var numb = $(this).value();

    setTime(product[numb].time);
    setWater(product[numb].woda);
    setSalt(product[numb].salt);
    setComment(product[numb].comment);

});

function setTime(time) {
    $('#time').html(time);
}

function setWater(water) {
    $('#water').html(water);
}

function setSalt(salt) {
    $('#salt').html(salt);
}

function setComment(comment) {
    $('#comment').html(comment);
}
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```